# Difference between redirect:prefix and forward:prefix in Spring MVC3.0

Tags: redirect, spring-mvc

Hi I am new to Spring MVC i am following Spring reference documentaion I have doubt in view resolver. Here is my sample code.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/form")
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String setupForm() {
        // do my stuff
        return "myform";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processForm(ModelMap model) {            
        // process form data

        model.addAttribute("notification", "Successfully did it!");
        return "redirect:/form";
    }
}
```

here i am using two controllers, the first one returns `"myform"` and second one returns `"redirect:/form"`. My question is, what is the difference between these two and how it works?

Answer (score -1):

If you are familiar with jsp servlet, I think you can know the difference between redirect and forward, or you can get tons of answers from google. Then I want to explain a bit about how Spring does this. in **setupForm** method, it returns myform, then according to your view resovler configuration, it will try to find a myform.jsp or another likes this, and if your view resovler is **internalresourceviewresovler**, Spring will do a forward **automatically** and try to find this jsp in web-inf directory, if not, you have to specify a forward prefix. and for **processForm** method, that after return **redirect:/form**, it will force browser to send a new request **/form** to server which can be got by spring mvc and it will handle it with the related method.